# Reason to stay somewhere, that isn't survival

Tags: survival

As I read some questions here, I noticed that a good reason for something living to be somewhere is often survival. But what are the cases when it isn't? What could be a good main reason for a living being to stay in a place that isn't survival? Of course, the living beings can survive in such a place, but what makes them stay wouldn't be to survive.

One example would be that Mankind can try (and succeed) to live in the desert only to prove a point, or gather luxury ressources, etc, but it's not really the best place to live in the world.

Two cases:

- The living being is human or human-like: it has society, economy, and all of the 'futile' ways to spend its time;
- The living being is closer to an animal, or is one: it searches for food and sleeps most of the time.

PS: Unfortunately, I can't think or find a good tag for this question... So feel free to edit it :)

Comment: Hey Keker, I am not sure what you are trying to ask here.  If something has everything it needs to survive then it stays based upon want or some responsibility based on personal choice...unless there is slavery...anyway if you could edit the question to clarify what your question really is that would be helpful. As it stands its a little unclear.

Comment: @James - At the risk of putting words in Keker's mouth, I read this as reasons why a living being (intelligent or otherwise) might stay in a place it CAN survive - but that the reasons aren't related to its survival.  (Which leads me to think about this as living in a place that isn't "the best" from a survival viewpoint.)

Comment: @Ghotir, nearly! Something I have in mind is that humans can clearly stay somewhere where the life is tough just to prove a point or have glory. I was wondering if there could be anything else, not necessarily for humans.

Answer (score 10):

Off the top of my head...

An intelligent being might stay somewhere because of aesthetics (it's pretty), because of religion (it's holy), because of history (this is where our forefathers built their home; this is where my spouse died), because of perceived economic value (hard to grow crops, but this mine is nice), etc.

Non-intelligent beings might stay somewhere because it's safer (there are predators in the best forage grounds), because it's more comfortable (more warm sunbeams to sleep in here), because of a specific sense (this place "smells" like home), etc.

I'm sure there are plenty of other reasons as well.

Comment: Staying somewhere because it's safe has to do with survival, but otherwise have my upvote.

Answer (score 3):

**Trade**

Many of today's major cities were founded as centers of trade. Look at New York City, Cape Town, Massalia (Marseilles), Venice, Singapore, and Hong Kong, just to name a few. These sites were ideal for an entry point to a larger area, generally at the mouth of a river, or a particularly safe harbor. This trade was not required for the city's survival, but the flow of goods and people enriched the city both monetarily and culturally. People flocked to these cities because there were exotic goods to be found and money to be made.